# Storing password as md5 in neo4j?

Tags: authentication, neo4j, md5

MAJOR EDIT: I have a Neo4j database record of user information like name, location, email & password. I want to store the password records in md5 for security reasons. How can I convert the password entered by the user to md5 in the Neo4j database?

It's a Django app, and I need to secure user information with storing the password as md5 in Neo4j.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think you might need to add a little more detail re what you are trying to do, how Neo4j integrates with your application, what technologies you are using etc etc.

Comment: Neo4j aside, you should really really use something better than MD5.  Ideally bcrypt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode it in the application level before storing it into neo4j. Like you would do with other databases.

In django it would be :

```
userpwd=str("mySuperPassword")
hashedpw=md5.new(userpwd)
```

// Then store it into neo

Comment: I think that MD5 is such a bad idea that I'm hijacking the answer comment thread as well.  Use BCrypt! http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: I understand your pov ;-)

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Md5 is super-easy to crack. Bcrypt is mentioned as a good alternative. You may also want to take a look at other modern encryption libraries such as libsodium or NaCl.

Answer (score 3):

Using MD5 for password storage is a bad idea.  MD5 passwords are far too easy to crack and have been for several years.  Use bcrypt in a programming language of your choice until someone implements strong crypto in Neo4J.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about MD5 storage, let Neo4j handle it for you. You can use the API to let a user set a password on first use [[1](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html#rest-api-user-status-on-first-access)], and have the user authenticate secure on subsequent use [[2](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html#rest-api-changing-the-user-password)]. See also the documentation [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html#rest-api-changing-the-user-password).

[1] URL: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html#rest-api-user-status-on-first-access

[2] URL: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html#rest-api-changing-the-user-password

Comment: Thanks. But my problem isn't with the Neo4j database account access. I edited the question. I have a node for user information (lets say "user" node), and want to keep track the password in the database via their md5 equivalents for security reasons.

Comment: There is no simple answer I am afraid. Also, you may want to reconsider storing the password instead of the hash.